# 'node' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file. - Browsershot

Tags: php, node.js, laravel, xampp

I have installed Browsershot to `Laravel` the same way like here (https://github.com/spatie/browsershot ) and when I try to do something it gives me this error.

> The command "node
>   "C:\xp\htdocs\staticit\vendor\spatie\browsershot\src/../bin/browser.js"
>   "{\"url\":\"https://google.com\",\"action\":\"screenshot\",\"options\":{\"type\":\"png\",\"path\":\"C:\xp\htdocs\staticit\app\Http\Controllers/temp/testScreenshot.png\",\"args\":[],\"viewport\":{\"width\":800,\"height\":600}}}""
>   failed. Exit Code: 1(General error) Working directory:
>   C:\xp\htdocs\staticit\public Output: ================ Error Output:
>   ================ 'node' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

I have installed node modules in my Laravel project root folder and when I write node -v in my cmd it is recognized.

**Note: I'm using Win7 , Laravel 5.7 and node ,php latest version.

Comment: Node is definitely in your path?

Comment: @Prodigle Yes, it is.

Comment: I have same issue.

Comment: got same error .

Answer (score 1):

So the problem was that my OS is Windows, when I switched to Ubunto everething worked fine. I have opened this issue in the github repo of the creator, but he closed it because he dosen't use Windows.